# Can we mock a spy object using mockito?

Tags: java, mockito, junit4

I have a class called RadiationControl and I created a spy for it in the following way.

```
RadiationControl radCtrl = new RadiationControl();
RadiationControl spyRadCtrl = Mockito.spy(radCtrl);
```

I have a chained method call inside a different class called StationMonitor which is being called by using the RadiationControl object. When I am trying to use the above created spy and trying to access that which has method parameters and they vary from time to time.

```
StationMonitorObject stationMonitorObject = radCtrl.getStationMonitorLoader().retrieveCVStationMonitorObject(Long.parseLong(syngId), status);
```

Thus with the above syntax when I try to stub the spy for that method call it's complaining to stub properly.

```
StationMonitorLoader stationMonitorLoader = StationMonitorLoader.getLoader(domain);
  Mockito.doReturn(stationMonitorLoader).when(spyRadCtrl).getStationMonitorLoader();

  Mockito.doReturn(stationMonitorObject).when(stationMonitorLoader).retrieveCVStationMonitorObject(any(Long.class), null);
```

Is there any better approach to deal such scenario ?

Comment: What does "it's complaining to stub properly" mean?  Are you getting some kind of error message?  At run time or compile time?  Also, what is `stationMonitorLoader`?  Another spy or mock?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any better approach to deal such scenario ?

Yes.

The problem here is:

> ```
> radCtrl.getStationMonitorLoader()
>        .retrieveCVStationMonitorObject(Long.parseLong(syngId), status);
> ```

This is a violation of the *law of demeter* (aka *don't talk to strangers!*).

The method `retrieveCVStationMonitorObject()` should be available  in class `RadiationControl` and delegate the call to *its* dependency  (which looks like being a `StationMonitorLoader`...)